# Localization broken for UISegmentedControl in Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, localization, uisegmentedcontrol

Localization from storyboard for UISegmentedControl seems to not be working with the Italian language.
It's fine if I localize it programmatically, setting all its titles with NSLocalizedStrings.

Can anybody confirm that?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [OpenRadar](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2159402) on this...